# Getting Cloudwatch metric with Boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I managed to invoke a custom cloudwatch agent to get percentage of disks using the following config.json

```
{
"metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
        "LogicalDisk": {
            "measurement": [
                "% Free Space"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the graph under Cloudwatch > Metrics.  The source of the graphs shows:

```
"region": "us-east-1",
"metrics": [
    [ "CWAgent", "LogicalDisk % Free Space", "instance", "C:", "InstanceId", "i-0e39e66f751dfbf46", "objectname", "LogicalDisk" ]
],
"period": 300,
"stat": "Average",
"view": "timeSeries",
"stacked": false
```

Then I wrote this boto3 client but couldn't get the datapoints.

```
    response = cw_cli.get_metric_statistics(Namespace='CWAgent',
                                        MetricName='LogicalDisk % Free Space',
                                        Dimensions=[
                                            {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': 'i-123456787654'},
                                        ],
                                        StartTime=datetime(2020, 8, 12, 11, 00, 00),
                                        EndTime=datetime(2020, 8, 12, 12, 00, 00),
                                        Period=60,
                                        Statistics=['Average', 'Minimum', 'Maximum'],
                                        Unit='Percent')
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to find this looking for an answer myself last night. You may have already figured this out, but for anyone like me who still couldn't find an answer... it's this:

For this particular `MetricName`, change the `Unit` to `None`. You'd think `Percent` is the obvious answer here, but it's not. Also, the dimensions have to match the dimensions listed in `list_metrics` for the instance.